# Flask app.run(ssl_context='adhoc') has no effect

Tags: flask, https

I am trying to have a basic Flask app run on "https":

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')
```

However, it starts on http:

> - Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000

In fact, I have a more elaborate Flask app that I moved onto https a couple of days ago, and it worked! However, I started it again today, and it got stuck on http://.

So, I created the basic script shown above to see if it works, but it doesn't.

I'll be grateful for any hints..

Thanks!